# Unplugged Windows 10 laptop starts from shutdown when waking from sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep, asus-laptop

My laptop seems like it is starting from a shutdown after I wake it from sleep mode (either by opening the lid or pressing the power button). However, this only happens when it's unplugged. When it's plugged in, it wakes from sleep correctly. I've reproduced this consistently. Note that the laptop seems like it's going to sleep mode correctly, it's just when I wake it up that the issue arises. Any help on how to even start troubleshooting this would be appreciated.

Laptop: Windows 10 Home on Asus Zenbook UX305

Comment: Does the battery hold a charge properly?

Comment: How long is there between going to sleep and waking up when the cord is unplugged?

Comment: If you run out of battery while sleeping the machine will shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

As DavidPostill states, the battery charge determines when the laptop must shut down completely (*Sleep* continuously drains the battery), but the power plan also determines that timeout.

You can view and change the amount of time before *Sleep* terminates in shutdown:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> and enter *Power Options*.
2. Select *Change plan settings* for the plan in use (checked).
3. Select *Change advanced power settings*.
4. Under *Sleep*, note how long the wait before *Hibernate* (or complete shutdown, if *Hibernate* is not enabled).
5. Also, scroll to the *Battery* options to see how much margin is allowed before shutdown.

[image: Advanced Power Options for Sleep]

Answer (score 0):

I have an Asus ROG GL552VW and I had the same issue i.e. reset immediately after wake up, but only on battery, if it was plugged in it would wake up normally.
Problem solved after I switched Power plans from Balanced to High Performance.

Comment: Why not just write only answer part ? ie. `Switch power plans from Balanced to High Performance`